# Getting actual device orientation lock in React Native (expo)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, screen-orientation

I wan't to show a message to the user if his device orientation is locked, and I'm having trouble accessing this info.

I've tried using **getOrientationLockAsync**, but that only returns the apps orientation lock. Here is the code I've us

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import * as ScreenOrientation from 'expo-screen-orientation';

export default function App() {
  ScreenOrientation.getOrientationLockAsync().then((res) => {
    console.log('getOrientationLockAsync', res)
  })
  
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

And this always returns whathever is set in the app.json regardles if I set the device orientation to **Portrait** or **Landscape**.

If my app.json looks like this:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "expo-ex",
    "slug": "expo-ex",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "default",
    ...
  }
}
```

The **getOrientationLockAsync** will always return '0' which corelates to 'OrientationLock.DEFAULT' even if I lock the device orientation to **Landscape**.

I also tried the fuction **ScreenOrientation.getPlatformOrientationLockAsync()** but that also doesn't do the trick.

The device I'm using is Samsung s10e and the SDK version of expo is 40.